# Sqlsrv extension for php 5.6 x86 and Windows Server 2012

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I've been running in circles for about three days now. I've just set up a local SQL database and I transferred some php code I'm trying to run on it. Problem is, this php code uses the sqlsrv library and runs on a slightly older version of microsoft server.

No matter what I do, I can't get sqlsrv to load. I have quadruple checked my php.ini file, I had this problem with PHP 7, read some resources online that said sqlsrv doesn't work with php7, so I switched to php 5.6. I've tried the microsoft driver for sqlsrv for this php distribution. I've downloaded the SQL server native client.

Through all this, I can't get phpinfo() to load up sqlsrv. I've read various sources saying that sqlsrv isn't available for this version of PHP either, but I want a straight answer before I go through the motions of installing a different php.

Any help is appreciated. I've been through a lot of stack overflow questions and still couldn't find a straight answer, I'm happy to provide more information if required. (Also, I'm a noob in this kind of development, so forgive me if any of this is unclear)

Thank you!

Comment: Check https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 . The drivers support both PHP 7 and 5.6 (they are different .exe files). Check your php error log, the problem was probably logged in there.

Comment: I will give this another try, but the last time I tried it I couldn’t get it working. The only culprit I can find is that windows 2012 isn’t actually listed there. Only up to 2008. Thank you for the reply, nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

I ended up using an "unofficial" sqlsrv extension found here: https://onedrive.live.com/?id=669EE24817961774%21123&cid=669EE24817961774

I think I have an odd combination of 32 bit php 5.6 and Windows Server 2012. Hopefully this helps someone!